# Identical tables, different performance in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

We've been having problems with performance for a SQL Server at work. Queries that run well on one server run awfully on another (e.g. 20 minutes vs 16 hours, same box specs, seemingly same setup).

To try and understand the issue, I set up a update query (around 2m record table). When I tried to run it on a particular table, it could take anywhere up to 20 minutes to run. When I create a copy of that same table (i.e. `select * into new table`) and run the same query on the copy it only takes 30 seconds.

For info, none of the tables have indexes on them.

I'm a bit limited in terms of what info I can share, but any ideas what could be causing an issue like this?

Comment: Are the plans identical? Are the files on the same physical store? Are the same compressing settings used? Are they both heap/cluster? Has the old table been rebuilt (see REBUILD)? Are there any triggers and/or replication? Is there other contentious access to the original table (see locks and transactions, eg) during the query?

Comment: Anyway, seems like the DBA stack exchange might be more appropriate.

Comment: Have you [updated statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Are there other users accessing the slow table while you are the only one accessing the fast one?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! Both heap, same physical store, tried rebuilding, identical plans, no contentious access that I can see, Same compression. No idea what trigger / replication is so I'll read up on that and see how I go.

Comment: I'm alone on the server thankfully so no other users are the issue. Have also updated statistics with no luck.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the hardware itself? We had SQL Server running on a Dell server that periodically slowed to a crawl. Reboot did not fix it - you had to remove power (both power supplies). Then the server would be normal for a long period of time, before the slowdown happening again randomly. It turned out to be a firmware issue and required an update.

Comment: I can reproduce the same results over and over again, on multiple days, and between restarts. So I figure it's low likelihood of it being a hardware failure (ie not just bad luck or timing of the runs).

Answer (score 0):

Creating just another table might not have all the indexes was created on the original table along with the data ,or Query optimization configs might not be the same as the original table. DBAs will be able to help you why its talking this much time.

Comment: Thanks! As mentioned, no indexes on this one as part of the test, so don't think this will be the cause.

Comment: When you copy from the existing table, that doesn't create the primary keys from the original table. That's is the issue. You need to add them manually.